# Python: flip a precise bit in a double

Tags: python, floating-point, bit

I need to flip a precise bit in a double with Python.

More precisely, I need a function that takes as arguments the double X and the position i and return the corrupted value of X, in which the i-th bit in the double-precision has been flipped.

For example: `bitflip(34.501,63)` should return `-34.501` (the last bit is the sign).

For now, I have got this function:

```
from struct import *

def bitflip(x,pos):
    fs = pack('d',x)
    bval = list(unpack('BBBBBBBB',fs))
    [q,r] = divmod(pos,8)
    bval[q-1] ^= 1 << r
    fs = pack('BBBBBBBB', *bval)
    fnew=unpack('d',fs)
    return fnew[0]
```

But it doesn't flip the i-th bit.

Comment: A `float` (single precision) is 32 bit, a double precision is 64 bit. Does that help?

Comment: sorry I am lacking of precision. I am working with floating-point variable with double-precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is located here:

```
bval[q-1] ^= 1 << r
#    ^why q-1?
```

You use `divmod(1,8)` is `(0,1)` (the first byte - well zero'th since arrays start at `0`, second bit, again starting from `0`). Therefore you should use `q` instead of `q-1`:

```
from struct import *

def bitflip(x,pos):
    fs = pack('d',x)
    bval = list(unpack('BBBBBBBB',fs))
    [q,r] = divmod(pos,8)
    bval[q] ^= 1 << r
    fs = pack('BBBBBBBB', *bval)
    fnew=unpack('d',fs)
    return fnew[0]
```

This gives the intended behavior:

```
>>> bitflip(34.501,63)
-34.501
```

Comment: @pl-94: well you did most of the work correctly. Don't be too hard on yourself ;)